# Rename a image file in play framework

Tags: file, playframework, playframework-2.0, file-rename

I am trying to rename a image file play framework's public/images folder. I tried to use play.getFile() and viirtualFile class, irrespective of what i use i end up with the exception below.
Please let me know if i am missing something.

```
VirtualFile vf = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("path to public/images/old file name.jpg");
File file = vf.getRealFile();
file.renameTo(new File("path to public/images/new file name.jpg");
```

Error:

```
play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@450b9338 on controllers.Admin
at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:556)
at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:167)
at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:431)
at play.Play.start(Play.java:516)
at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:630)
at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.ContinuationEnhancer on controllers.Admin
at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:302)
at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:551)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

public, app and conf is packed into the application jar when you package your app for production use with 'play dist' so regardless of if you get it to work in dev mode it will not work in production.